C++ MySQL X DevAPI Connection Error: Undefined Reference
I'm trying to establish a basic MySQL C++ connection using MySQL X DevAPI. However, when compiling my code, I'm getting the following error:
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Settings_impl::Data::init_connection_attr()'
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::from_utf8(mysqlx::abi2::r0::string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Result_detail::Result_detail(mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Result_init&)'
undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::internal::Doc_result_detail::get_doc()'

It seems like the linker is unable to find the definitions for these MySQL X DevAPI functions. I have included the correct include and library paths. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.3/include/mysql.h"
#include "mysqlx/xdevapi.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Connecting to MySQL server..." << std::endl;

    try {
        mysqlx::Session sess("localhost", 33060, "root", "root");
        mysqlx::Schema db = sess.getSchema("test");

        mysqlx::Collection myColl = db.getCollection("my_collection");

        mysqlx::DocResult myDocs = myColl.find("name like :param")
                                         .limit(1)
                                         .bind("param", "L%")
                                         .execute();

        std::cout << myDocs.fetchOne() << std::endl;
    } catch (const mysqlx::Error &e) {
        std::cout << "MySQL X DevAPI Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


I'm using the following command to compile the code:
g++ -std=c++20 -o test_sql test_sql.cpp -I"C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.3/include" -L"C:/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.3/lib64/vs14" -lmysqlcppconn8


you can't link to visual studio libraries from gcc, you'll need to build the library from source with gcc

Thanks @AlanBirtles, that was what the issue was. Thanks for you assistance.
